# How to set a gradient backgroundColor of Navigation Bar with UINavigationBarAppearance in iOS 15 (Objective C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, background-color

I'm using iOS 15 with Xcode 13.0, and I  have encountered a known problem whit the navigation bar due to UIKit which has extended the usage of the scrollEdgeAppearance.
So I solved the issue using this answer [iOS 15 Navigation Bar Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111478/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent) .

Now I have another problem.
I have to set the background color of the navigation bar to have a gradient color, from the starColor to the endColor.

This is the situation in iOS 15:
[image]
and iOS 14.6:
[image]

Now I want it to work in iOS 15 as it did in iOS 14.8.

This is the code that I added in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, based on the solutions found on stackoverflow:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if (@available(iOS 15, *)){
    UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [[UINavigationBarAppearance alloc] init];
    [appearance configureWithTransparentBackground];
    [appearance setBackgroundColor:startColor];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].standardAppearance = appearance;
    [UINavigationBar appearance].scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
} }
```

I want to change the line [appearance setBackgroundColor:startColor] in order to have a gradient background (from startColor to endColor).
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 15 Navigation Bar Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111478/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent)

Comment: A simple way would be to add a `CALayer` to `navigationItem`'s `titleView`.

Comment: @ManWithBear no it doesn't solve the gradient issue.

Comment: @ElTomato when I try to add CALayer to navigationItem the navigation bar turns black.