# iOS: Can't change navigation bar color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Can't change navigation bar background color. I've tried setting colors to navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor and navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor, such as UIColor.red in the following example, but a white UIImage appears above the navigation bar color in the view hierarchy, as shown in this image: https://imguh.com/image/CBXaj

Also tried making navigation bar translucent and opaque, to no effect. I can change the button colors and customize other elements, but not change the background color of the bar. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You need property `backgroundColor` of `UINavigationBarAppearance`

Comment: tried setting that too, like this UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green. it has no effect, the green doesn't appear in the view hierarchy

Comment: No it's not `UINavigationBarApperance`, you need  set it in `UINavigationBar.standardAppearance` and `UINavigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance`

Comment: tried setting UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown and UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance?.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown but had no effect

Comment: Or that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69135729/1934750?

Comment: you should not use image links as they can break with time

Answer (score 15):

The following code should do the trick for you:

**Background Colour**

```
// This will change the navigation bar background color
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // your colour here

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

*Place this inside the `viewDidLoad()` function within your ViewController*

**Title Colour**

If you want to also change the navigation bar title appearance, then apply the following code before you set the `standardAppearance` and `scrollEdgeAppearance`:

```
// This will alter the navigation bar title appearance
let titleAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple] //alter to fit your needs
appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleAttribute
```

**Entire code:**

```
// This will change the navigation bar background color
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        
// This will alter the navigation bar title appearance
let titleAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple] //alter to fit your needs
appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleAttribute

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q61w9.png)

Comment: works perfect! thanks.