# UISearchController - Is there a way to avoid the top space/ padding when showing result with a new controller?

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I setup my `UISearchController` (I am using a new controller `BackupSearchResultsVC` to show the search result)

```
class BackupViewViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let backupSearchResultsVC = BackupSearchResultsVC.instanceFromNib()
        backupSearchResultsVC.postInit(nsBackup)
        
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: backupSearchResultsVC)
        
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "search_notes".localized
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        
        return searchController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        /** Specify that this view controller determines how the search controller is presented.
            The search controller should be presented modally and match the physical size of this view controller.
        */
        definesPresentationContext = true
        
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
```

---

This is the UI before search begins.

[image]

Once the search begins (The search bar will move upward to block the title bar when the search text field is in focus), there is a wide gap between the search result (red background) and the search text bar.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid the gap, yet able to use a new controller to show the result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the presentation is full screen and the `searchResultsController` goes under the nav bar which has the search bar.

I believe this has something to do with the autolayout constraints / background color set up of your `view controller` set up to be the `searchResultsController`

For example, I have set up the like this:

```
class BackupSearchResultsVC: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating
{
    let resultsView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureResultsView()
    }
    
    private func configureResultsView()
    {
        resultsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        resultsView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(resultsView)
        
        // Add constraints with top anchor of 200
        view.addConstraints([
            
            resultsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            resultsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            resultsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            resultsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)

        ])
    }
```

[image: Custom UIViewController for SearchResultsController not full screen swift iOS]

Because of the top anchor, it gives me the same results you see:

If you want to keep the red view's position as it is, add a background color to your view controller's main view

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Give a background color
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    configureResultsView()
}
```

[image: UISearchController with custom UIViewController as search results controller swift iOS]

Or you could just remove the constraint to the top

```
// Add constraints without top anchor of 200
view.addConstraints([
    
    resultsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    resultsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    resultsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    resultsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)

])
```

[image: Custom UIViewController for UISearchController swift iOS]

If this still does not work, try `backupSearchResultsVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` during your set up

Give one of these a go and see if it solves your problem

**Update based on Mr Cheng's**

It seems giving the UIViewController used as the `searchResultsController` seems to make the UINavigationBar go transparent when active and the full view controller is shown behind:

[image: Custom UIViewController as search results controller UISearchController iOS Swift]

This is different to what I see running the same code:

[image: Custom UIViewController for UISearchController search results iOS Swift]

This leads me to believe this is iOS related as my device is iOS 14 and the result you see is probably iOS 15.

Digging a bit deeper, I came across [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111478/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent) which suggests by default, the bar tint is transparent on iOS 15.

So I believe you might need to set a custom background color for the nav bar in iOS 15 as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69123993/1619193) perhaps

Comment: Hi, I tend to produce a simple example - https://github.com/yccheok/SearchBarIssue But I am still not able to achieve your outcome. Do you have idea why? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello @CheokYanCheng, I think this could be iOS related. Please see my updated answer if it helps you. At the moment I cannot test iOS 15, however I added some suggestions which might help.