Why tabbar items showing with left alignment in ios18?

My app displays tab bar items evenly in iOS versions below 18, which is normal. However, in iOS 18, there are occasional cases where they appear to be displayed like images. How can I resolve this? I am using Apple's standard UITabBarController and have not customized the tab bar item content.
Correct display tabbar items in iOS 18.
 init(title: String = "", image: String = "", sysImaged: Bool = true, rootViewController: UIViewController) {
    super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    self.title = title
    if sysImaged {
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: image)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(systemName: "\(image).fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    } else {
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: image)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "\(image)_sel")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
    self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2)
    self.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.delegate =  self
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111478/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent
    // 导航栏滚动透明问题
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    }
}

func configureTabbar() {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], for: .selected)
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.theme.tabBarBackgroundColor
    tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.theme.tabbarItemSelectedColor
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor =  UIColor.theme.tabbarItemNormalColor
}


Please show related codes.

Did you find a solution?

Try these two things:
UITabBar().itemWidth = self.window!.frame.size.width

OR
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill

